# React-native app with webpack 5. Build error: Webpack is not recognising react-native-svg elements <G></G> or <Svg></Svg>

Tags: react-native, svg, webpack

I'm trying to run react-native app as html webpage with webpack 5. But when I try ro tum it with

```
yarn webpack serve -d source-map --mode development --config ./web/webpack.config.js --color --hot
```

command I get this error

```
ERROR in ./assets/icons/icons.js 10:7
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (10:7)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
|       _template: {
|               viewBox: "0 0 32 32",
>               svg: <Svg></Svg>,
|       },
|
```

Here's my package.json

```
{
    "name": "adapto",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "private": true,
    "license": "MIT",
    "scripts": {
        "android": "react-native run-android",
        "ios": "react-native run-ios",
        "lint": "eslint .",
        "start": "react-native start",
        "test": "jest",
        "pod-install": "RCT_NEW_ARCH_ENABLED=1 bundle exec pod install",
        "build:android-bundle": "react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res",
        "build:android-appdebug": "cd android && ./gradlew assembleDebug",
        "build:androidapk": "react-native run-android",
        "cc": "yarn cache clean",
        "assets": "yarn react-native-asset",
        "premissions": "yarn react-native setup-ios-permissions && cd ios && pod install && cd ..",
        "pod": "cd ios && pod install && cd ..",
        "bootsplash": "react-native generate-bootsplash ./assets.src/logo/bootsplash.png --background-color=000000 --logo-width=200 --assets-path=./src/assets --flavor=main --platforms=android,ios",
        "postinstall": "react-native setup-ios-permissions && pod-install",
        "rename": "yarn react-native-rename \"adapto\" -b \"pl.myhotelsoftware.pizzatruck\" --skipGitStatusCheck",
        "android-release": "yarn react-native run-android --mode=release",
        "android-bundle": "cd android && ./gradlew bundleRelease && cd ..",
        "android-clean": "cd android && ./gradlew clean && cd ..",
        "git": "git add . && git commit -m \"WIP\" && git push -f origin main",
        "start-webpack": "webpack-dev-server --mode development --open",
        "build": "webpack --mode=production --node-env=production",
        "build:dev": "webpack --mode=development",
        "build:prod": "webpack --mode=production --node-env=production",
        "watch": "webpack --watch",
        "serve": "webpack serve",
        "webbuild": "yarn webpack --mode production --config ./web/webpack.config.js",
        "webdev": "yarn webpack serve -d source-map --mode development --config ./web/webpack.config.js --color --hot"
    },
    "reactNativePermissionsIOS": [
        "LocationWhenInUse",
        "LocationAccuracy",
        "Camera",
        "Notifications"
    ],
    "dependencies": {
        "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.17.11",
        "@react-native-community/blur": "^4.3.0",
        "@react-native-community/geolocation": "^3.0.5",
        "@react-native-community/toolbar-android": "^0.2.1",
        "@react-native-firebase/app": "^17.4.2",
        "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^17.4.2",
        "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.7",
        "@react-navigation/core": "^6.4.8",
        "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.6",
        "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.16",
        "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.3",
        "expo-asset": "^8.9.1",
        "expo-blur": "^12.2.2",
        "expo-core": "^3.0.1",
        "expo-font": "^11.1.1",
        "expo-linear-gradient": "^12.1.1",
        "expo-modules-core": "^1.2.6",
        "geolib": "^3.3.3",
        "javascript-time-ago": "^2.5.9",
        "pod-install": "^0.1.38",
        "react": "18.2.0",
        "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
        "react-native": "0.71.3",
        "react-native-actionsheet": "^2.4.2",
        "react-native-animatable": "^1.3.3",
        "react-native-asset": "^2.1.0",
        "react-native-base64": "^0.2.1",
        "react-native-bootsplash": "^4.6.0",
        "react-native-device-info": "^10.6.0",
        "react-native-eject": "^0.2.0",
        "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.12.0",
        "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.6.2",
        "react-native-localize": "^2.2.6",
        "react-native-md5": "^1.0.0",
        "react-native-permissions": "^3.8.0",
        "react-native-picker-select": "^8.0.4",
        "react-native-qrcode-svg": "^6.2.0",
        "react-native-reanimated": "^3.3.0",
        "react-native-rename": "^3.2.12",
        "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.5.0",
        "react-native-screens": "^3.20.0",
        "react-native-shared-element": "^0.8.8",
        "react-native-store-version": "^1.4.1",
        "react-native-svg": "^13.8.0",
        "react-native-svg-icon": "^0.10.0",
        "react-native-toast-message": "^2.1.6",
        "react-native-web": "^0.19.6",
        "react-navigation-shared-element": "3.1.3",
        "react-redux": "^8.0.5",
        "yarn": "^1.22.19"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.0",
        "@babel/runtime": "^7.20.0",
        "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^3.2.0",
        "@tsconfig/react-native": "^2.0.2",
        "@types/jest": "^29.2.1",
        "@types/react": "^18.2.14",
        "@types/react-native": "^0.72.2",
        "@types/react-test-renderer": "^18.0.0",
        "@welldone-software/why-did-you-render": "^7.0.1",
        "babel-jest": "^29.2.1",
        "babel-loader": "^9.1.2",
        "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^5.0.0",
        "babel-plugin-react-native-web": "^0.19.6",
        "eslint": "^8.19.0",
        "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.3",
        "jest": "^29.2.1",
        "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.73.7",
        "prettier": "^2.4.1",
        "react-native-typescript-transformer": "^1.2.13",
        "react-test-renderer": "18.2.0",
        "typescript": "^5.1.6",
        "url-loader": "^4.1.1",
        "webpack": "^5.88.1",
        "webpack-cli": "^5.1.4",
        "webpack-dev-server": "^4.15.1"
    },
    "jest": {
        "preset": "react-native"
    }
}
```

metro.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  transformer: {
    getTransformOptions: async () => ({
      transform: {
        experimentalImportSupport: false,
        inlineRequires: true,
      },
    }),
  },
};
```

and my webpack.config.js

```
const path = require("path")
const webpack = require("webpack")

const appDirectory = path.resolve(__dirname, "../")

// This is needed for webpack to compile JavaScript.
// Many OSS React Native packages are not compiled to ES5 before being
// published. If you depend on uncompiled packages they may cause webpack build
// errors. To fix this webpack can be configured to compile to the necessary
// `node_module`.
const babelLoaderConfiguration = {
    test: /\.(js)|(jsx)$/,
    // Add every directory that needs to be compiled by Babel during the build.
    include: [
        path.resolve(appDirectory, "index.web.js"),
        path.resolve(appDirectory, "src"),
        path.resolve(appDirectory, "App.js"),
        path.resolve(appDirectory, "node_modules/react-native-uncompiled"),
        path.resolve(appDirectory, "node_modules/react-native-toast-message"),
        path.resolve(appDirectory, "node_modules/react-native-animatable"),
        path.resolve(appDirectory, "node_modules/react-native-actionsheet"),
        path.resolve(appDirectory, "node_modules/react-native-picker-select"),
        path.resolve(appDirectory, "node_modules/react-native-qrcode-svg"),
        path.resolve(appDirectory, "node_modules/@react-native-picker"),
        path.resolve(appDirectory, "node_modules/react-native-web"),
        path.resolve(appDirectory, "node_modules/react-native/Libraries"),
        path.resolve(appDirectory, "node_modules/expo-asset"),
        path.resolve(appDirectory, "node_modules/expo-font"),
        path.resolve(appDirectory, "node_modules/@react-native/assets"),

        path.resolve(appDirectory, "node_modules/react-native-svg"),
        path.resolve(appDirectory, "node_modules/react-native-svg-icon"),
        path.resolve(appDirectory, "node_modules/react-native-svg-web"),

        // path.resolve(appDirectory, "node_modules/"),
    ],
    use: {
        loader: "babel-loader",
        options: {
            cacheDirectory: true,
            // The 'metro-react-native-babel-preset' preset is recommended to match React Native's packager
            presets: ["module:metro-react-native-babel-preset"],
            // Re-write paths to import only the modules needed by the app
            plugins: ["react-native-web", ["module-resolver", { alias: { "^react-native$": "react-native-web" } }]],
        },
    },
}

// This is needed for webpack to import static images in JavaScript files.
const imageLoaderConfiguration = {
    test: /\.(gif|jpe?g|png|svg|webp)$/,
    use: {
        loader: "url-loader",
        options: {
            name: "[name].[ext]",
            esModule: false,
        },
    },
}

module.exports = {
    entry: [
        // load any web API polyfills
        // path.resolve(appDirectory, 'polyfills-web.js'),
        // your web-specific entry file
        path.resolve(appDirectory, "index.web.js"),
    ],

    // configures where the build ends up
    output: {
        filename: "bundle.web.js",
        path: path.resolve(appDirectory, "dist"),
    },

    
    // ...the rest of your config

    module: {
        rules: [babelLoaderConfiguration, imageLoaderConfiguration],
    },

    resolve: {
        // This will only alias the exact import "react-native"
        alias: {
            "react-native$": "react-native-web",
            // "react-native-svg": "react-native-svg-web",
        },

    
        extensions: [
            ".web.js",
            ".js",
            ".jsx",
            ".tsx",
            ".ts",
            ".native.js",
            ".kiosk.js",
            ".ios.js",
            ".android.js",
            //
        ],
    },
}
```

The strange thing is that I have compiled bundle.web.js which is 6 month old, and can't remember making any changes in the code.

Hop someone have any idea how to fix it.

I have tried adding following code to the babel part of webpack.config.js

```
path.resolve(appDirectory, "node_modules/react-native-svg"),
path.resolve(appDirectory, "node_modules/react-native-svg-icon"),
path.resolve(appDirectory, "node_modules/react-native-svg-web"),
```

but no luck.